Counting finger motions in reading verse in Parashat Ktoret
I was recently told that in addition to counting the eleven marks of incense with one's fingers during prayer, as is customary, some also count the six instances of the word "sammim" in the verse "ויאמר ה אל משה קח לך סמים נטף ושחלת וחלבנה סמים ולבנה זכה".
What is the reasoning behind or source for this additional finger-counting? Is it indeed acceptable according to the teachings of the Ari z”l, as I was told?

The question is about the counting in the 6 ingredients in the verse: ויאמר ה אל משה קח לך סמים נטף ושחלת וחלבנה סמים ולבנה זכה". Not the 11 ingredients of the Ktoret!!!!!!!!!

thats where the gemara in keritot comes in. you count, Samim as 2, the named ones as one each (thats 3 so total 5), then another samim as 5, then the last as 1. total of 11

There aren't six instances of the word "sammim"

@shmosel There are 6 type of Samanim (words) in the verse count them!!!! The Ari said it!!!!

That's not what you wrote in the question.

I think you are misinformed regarding 6. The verse has 4 unique spices, and says the words sammim twice. Sammim is plural - at least 2 (making 8). The Gemara explains how this verse is 11 and not 8. As far as I know, no one argues on the Gemara and says this verse is 6 or 8 and we learn the rest from another place. The Ben Ish Hai says to count as 11 while saying this verse, not 6

The Ben Ish Hai writes one should count the 11 with his fingers (Mikketz 8, see also Mikketz 6, Tisa 4). He says its proper

In order to help with proper concentration
It shows importance
You are doing something with your hands, not just mouth (dibbur, maaseh)
To do it with your right hand only

In regards to the passuk, he says to count the first "samim" as 2 and the second as 5, so you get the 11 in total. The reason for this is because the gemara states (K'ritot 6b)

The plural form of the phrase: “Take for you spices” is referring to two ingredients; “stacte, and onycha, and galbanum” are three ingredients; this results in a total of five; and the other mention of “spices” indicates that there are another five, i.e., that one should double the previous total, and this results in a total of ten. And finally, “pure frankincense” is one, and this results in a total of eleven (Steinsaltz).

